# Read bytes from a program and display result?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone have an example of how I can read the current data from a process and do something depending on what it is in visual studio?

**Example:** I'm playing a game called Final Fantasy 10 and I want to make a program to display information from the game as I'm playing it. Id want a way to tell me when I'm in battle or out of battle.

I don't want the ability to write anything to any program I'm getting data from since I just want to make sort of a companion program to display information in real time.

Thank you very much for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some programs that allow you to read the memory of a process like :
- CheatEngine https://cheatengine.org/

Comment: I'm trying to do something like that but I want to make my own companion application.

Comment: Also, check this : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670373/Csharp-Read-Write-another-Process-Memory

Comment: That is the exact type of example I was looking for. Thank you very much!